# Is it possible to get drivers for HP LaserJet 1200?

Tags: 10.04, drivers, printing, hp

I know about ndiswrapper for Windows network drivers. Is there anything like that for Windows printer related drivers? (Or a "universal" driver for Ubuntu by HP?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a universal driver called [hplip](http://hplipopensource.com) (Hewlett-Packard's Linux Imaging and Printing). It's installed by default (current version in Maverick is 3.10.6) so for most HP printers, you're able to plug it in and start printing straight away.

HP provide a searchable database of printers so you can [check to see if yours is compatible](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/supported_devices/index.html). They also provide [recommendations](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/recommended.html) so if you want a HP printer with full Linux support, you can check that list.

In your case, [the page for your LaserJet 1200](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/laserjet/hp_laserjet_1200.html) reports that it has full support. Congratulations.

Answer (score 2):

I think most HP printers work by default. Try plugging it!

Comment: +1 Thanks, Jorge answered right before you, so selected him as the answer. Again, thank you.

Comment: sure =), we're here to help

Answer (score 2):

According to the [HP LaserJet 1200](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/HP/HP-LaserJet_1200) page on the openprinting.org site this printer should be well supported. What happens when you plug it in (Update your question with what happens).

Comment: Yep, it's there, and works. Just went to the setup for printers, clicked add, and it was listed as a device. Click it and let it install using the default settings. After it was done I printed a test page. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We had a couple of those printers at work. I believe that the last one was changed around a month ago. They are not only plug'n'play on Ubuntu, they supported both PCL/5 and Postscript languages, using the generic postscript or pcl drivers also work.